# onNewIntent is not being called - only every second time?

Tags: android

I have a notification I am setting up

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);

mNotificationManager.notify(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_RESULT, mBuilder.build());
```

When I get my notification, the MainActivity.onNewIntent() is only getting called every second time for some reason. I have a debug log statement in there, and literally every 2nd time, the log does not trigger.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what are your requirements, but **onNewIntent** specifically declare in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) that

> This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in
>   their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag
>   when calling startActivity(Intent). In either case, when the activity
>   is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new
>   instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called
>   on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch
>   it.

Since you are not using **SINGLE_TOP** flag, the behavior might be inconsistent.

In any case, **onNewIntent** purpose is to send a new intent for an Activity that is already running. So, if your Activity is not running and you click on the notification to launch it, you will not get a call to **onNewIntent**. But you will get a call to **onCreate**, and then **onResume**. The second time you click the notification the Activity must be running and so instead of getting **onCreate** again, you are getting **onNewIntent**.

To test this, add logs to **onCreate** and **onNewIntent**.